# json_encode with double quotes passed into JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I have seen that this question has been asked too many times over the years. Still can't refrain from asking if anything was improved during this time.

Currently, I have PHP code:

```
$jsonData = json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

and then JS (Angular to be specific) comes into play:

```
var decoded = angular.fromJson('<?php echo $jsonData ; ?>');
```

The flags above do a very good job of keeping some of the issues at bay. However, given the example:

```
$data = ["name" => "Name \"Nickname\" Surname"];
```

JSON fails to parse. If I wrap the data with `addslashes()`, **it does work**, but then:

```
$data = ["name" => "Name 'Nickname' Surname"];
```

This fails.

Since the structure `$data` is highly unpredictable, and usually is 4-5 levels deep, my solution was:

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$item, $key){
    $item = str_replace('"', '\"', $item);
});
```

**This works**, however, I am looking for some more knowledgeable source. I've read some other SO questions where people escape not only double quotes but line feeds, carriage return and backslashes as well.

The last thing I need is to fall into edge case trap :)

Any hints for me?

Comment: escaping with slashes is giving you trouble because when you put it inside of yet another string inside your javascript file, the slash escapes the quote *before* sending it to JSON.parse, thus resulting in invalid json. The slash would need to be escaped as well as the quote in order for it to work. for example, `{"name": "Name \\"Nickname\\" Surname"}` would be interpreted by javascript as `"{"name": "Name \"Nickname\" Surname"}"` which is a string that is valid json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since json can be used directly as an object literal in javascript, you could use it like this:

```
var decoded = <?php echo $jsonData ; ?>;
```

thus eliminating the need to do any further parsing to avoid issues with `'` or `\` characters within the text. the `json_encode` should already be taking care of `"` charaters.

Comment: Whoa, this is really simple. I do feel a bit ashamed :) Thanks! :)

Comment: And, finally, 11 minutes are up and I can accept your answer :)

Comment: Oh, i didn't realize that was still a thing for users with more rep.

Comment: Neither was I. Apparently it is :)